# Sum of two times in the H:M format linux ubuntu

Tags: date, ubuntu, time

I got stuck in my script. I have `$time1`: for example `"2:05"` and `$time2`: `"2:30"`

Is there any easy way to add these two values? and get `$time3`: `"4:35"`, I've tried a lot of combinations with date -d, but can't solve it.

edit:
ok this is how i solved it:

```
EPOCH='jan 1 1970'
sum=0
for i in $var13 $var18
do
sum="$(date -u -d "$EPOCH $i" +%s) + $sum"
done
time9=$(echo $sum|bc) #time in seconds
time10=`date "-d@$time9" -u '+%H:%M'` #total time
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to convert both durations to seconds first:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub parse_min_sec {
    my ($dur) = @_;
    my ($min, $sec) = $dur =~ /\A (\d+) : (\d+) \z/xa
        or die "$0: can't parse duration: $dur\n";
    return $min * 60 + $sec;
}

sub format_min_sec {
    my ($sec) = @_;
    return sprintf "%d:%02d", int($sec / 60), $sec % 60;
}

my $time1 = "2:05";
my $time2 = "2:30";
my $time3 = format_min_sec(parse_min_sec($time1) + parse_min_sec($time2));
print "Result: $time3\n";
```

Output:

```
Result: 4:35
```

Comment: @R.W That probably means you didn't run this script with perl.

Comment: ah ok, its part of a sh script so wanted to keep it in the script, i posted the solution below my question. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to customize your code using Python

```python
def split_time(timestr):
    h, m = timestr.split(':')
    return int(h), int(m)

time1 = "2:05"
time2 = "2:30"

t1 = split_time(time1)
t2 = split_time(time2)
m = (t1[1]+t2[1])%60
h = t1[0]+t2[0]+(t1[1]+t2[1])//60
print(f'{h}:{m}')
```

You could also put the Python function into a script and call it from bash:

```
def add_times(tstr1, tstr2):
    t1 = [int(x) for x in tstr1.split(':')]
    t2 = [int(x) for x in tstr2.split(':')]
    m = (t1[1]+t2[1])%60
    h = t1[0]+t2[0]+(t1[1]+t2[1])//60
    return f'{h}:{m}'
```

You could do the same using bash but you need to perform arithmetic in bash which is not its strength. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183178/how-to-sum-time-using-bash